# jQuery fails when dropped into cshtml page with error " $(...) Charms is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, razor

I have been playing around with dropping some code from a html bootmetro page into a cshtml page.

When I run the original html page in the cshtml project it works fine; however, when I run the same code within a cshtml page a jquery feature to change the background colour to dark which is triggered by a settings icon returns this error:

```
Timestamp: 05/06/2013 13:46:56
Error: TypeError: $(...).charms is not a function
Source File: http://*l*o*c*a*l*h*o*s*t*:24349/assets/js/demo.js
Line: 29
```

I have tried the following answers that I researched with no joy:

• Put the code in @section scripts within the cshtml page:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>

    </script>
}
```

• Never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use helpers (or bundles which are recommended):

• Make sure that at the end of your _Layout.cshtml you don't have a
 `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` call because this would include jQuery twice.

• If at the end of `your _Layout.cshtml` you have a dedicated section for custom scripts like `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`, make sure that you have placed your custom script in that section (notice that since this RenderSection is at the end of the DOM you don't need to be wrapping your script in a document.ready event because by the time it executes, the DOM will already be loaded):

• Put the script tags in the Partial View itself where the form is generated from, it now knows what control to bind it to.

---

Here is the cshtml page:

```
@{

}
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
   <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

   <title>bigint</title>

    <!-- remove or comment this line if you want to use the local fonts -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootmetro.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootmetro-tiles.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/bootmetro-charms.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/metro-ui-light.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/icomoon.css">

   <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/js/ico/favicon.ico">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
   <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

   <script src="assets/js/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3182578-6']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      (function() {
         var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
         ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
   </script>


    <!-- bigInt favicon -->
    <link href="../bigInt_fav.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

 <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
      }
.pageborder {width:800px;
      margin:0 auto 0 auto;
      padding:5px;
      border:2px solid #eeeeee;
}

      /* Main marketing message and sign up button */
      .jumbotron {
        margin: 40px 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .jumbotron h1 {
        font-size: 100px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
      .jumbotron .lead {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 1.25;
      }

  /* Jumbotron button styling removed as it affects modal  button size */

      /* Supporting marketing content */
      .marketing {
        margin: 60px 0;
      }
      .marketing p + h4 {
        margin-top: 28px;
      }


      /* Customize the navbar links to be fill the entire space of the .navbar */
      .navbar .navbar-inner {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .navbar .nav {
        margin: 0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .navbar .nav li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 1%;
        float: none;
      }
      .navbar .nav li a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      }
      .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
        border-left: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      }
      .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
        border-right: 0;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      }

  .spinning_icons a:hover{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-out;
}         
      .social{
    float:right;
      }
       .like{
    float:right;
      }
       .logo{
 position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:10px;
      }         


</style>
<!-- I had to move a.trigger and active from stylex to here as links to plus & minus png did not work -->


</head>

<body data-accent="blue">


         <div id="top-info" class="pull-right">
         <a href="#" class="pull-left">


         </a>

          <a id="settings" class="pull-left" href="#">
            <b class="icon-settings"></b>
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   </header>

   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="metro span12">
            <div class="metro-sections">

               <div id="section1" class="metro-section tile-span-4">

                  <h2>bigint Pages</h2>

                  <a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blueDark" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img src="content/img/metro-tiles.jpg" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="column-text">
                        <div class="text4">Finished looking at the Windows 8 Metro style theme - then return home</div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="app-label">bigint Home</div>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile wide imagetext wideimage bg-color-orange" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <img src="content/img/appbar.png" alt=""/>
                     <div class="textover-wrapper bg-color-blue">
                        <div class="text2">About</div>
                     </div>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app wide bg-color-greenDark" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                       <b class="icon-home"></b>
                     </div>
                     <div class="app-label">Contact</div>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-purple" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                   <b class="icon-list"></b>
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Services</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-red" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                          <b class="icon-share"></b>
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Projects</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-yellow" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                          <img src="content/img/My Apps.png" />
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Quality Improvement</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-blueDark" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <b class="icon-globe"></b>
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Icons</span>
                  </a>

               </div>

               <div id="section2" class="metro-section tile-span-4">

                  <h2>Other bigint Sites </h2>

                  <a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blue" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img src="content/img/My Apps.png" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="column-text">
                        <div class="text">Grid system</div>
                        <div class="text">Layouts</div>
                        <div class="text">Responsive design</div>
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">bigint Blog</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile wide imagetext bg-color-blueDark" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img src="content/img/Coding app.png" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="column-text">
                        <div class="text">Typography</div>
                        <div class="text">Tables</div>
                        <div class="text">Forms</div>
                        <div class="text">Buttons</div>
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">bigint Jetstrap</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-orange" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img src="content/img//RegEdit.png" alt="" />
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Parners</span>
                  </a>

                  <a class="tile app bg-color-red" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <div class="image-wrapper">
                        <img src="content/img/Devices.png" alt="" />
                     </div>
                     <span class="app-label">Portfolio</span>
                  </a>

                          <a class="tile wide imagetext wideimage bg-color-white" href="./Home_Slide.html">
                     <iframe src="http://www.bigint.biz" width="306" height="200"></iframe>

                     <div class="textover-wrapper bg-color-blue">
                        <div class="text2">About</div>
                     </div>
                  </a>

               </div>


            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
   </div>



    <div id="charms" class="win-ui-dark">
      <div id="theme-charms-section" class="charms-section">
         <div class="charms-header">
            <a href="#" class="close-charms win-command">
               <span class="win-commandimage win-commandring">&#xe05d;</span>
            </a>
            <h2>Settings</h2>
         </div>

         <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

               <form class="">
                  <label for="win-theme-select">Change theme:</label>
                  <select id="win-theme-select" class="">
                     <option value="metro-ui-semilight">Semi-Light</option>
                     <option value="metro-ui-light">Light</option>
                     <option value="metro-ui-dark">Dark</option>
                  </select>
               </form>

            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>

   <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'>\x3C/script>")</script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootmetro.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootmetro-charms.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/holder.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".metro").metro();
   </script>


</body>

</html>
```

---

Here is the siteLayout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@Page.Title</title>

        <!-- Original <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" /> CSS -->
        <link href="@Href("~/bigInt_fav.ico")" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

              <!-- Le Bootstrap Styles -->
        <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

              <!-- Slideout CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylex.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

 <style type="text/css">

      body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
      }

         footer#site-footer {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
.pageborder {width:800px;
      margin:0 auto 0 auto;
      padding:5px;
      border:2px solid #eeeeee;
}

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
      .jumbotron {
        margin: 40px 0;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .jumbotron h1 {
        font-size: 100px;
        line-height: 1;
      }
      .jumbotron .lead {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 1.25;
      }


 /* Supporting marketing content */
      .marketing {
        margin: 60px 0;
      }
      .marketing p + h4 {
        margin-top: 28px;
      }


 /* Customize the navbar links to be fill the entire space of the .navbar */
      .navbar .navbar-inner {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .navbar .nav {
        margin: 0;
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .navbar .nav li {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 1%;
        float: none;
      }
      .navbar .nav li a {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
      }
      .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
        border-left: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
      }
      .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
        border-right: 0;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      }


.twitter{ background:url('images/Facebook_Cracked-48x48.png'); }
.delicious{ background:url('images/Twitter_Cracked_48x48.png'); }        

.spinning_icons a:hover{
transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-out;
}         
      .social{
    float:right;
      }
       .like{
    float:right;
      }


</style>


  <!-- Default Asp.net Script -->       
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

 <body>

<!-- Header section with social icons -->
 <header id="banner">

<!-- Script for spinning icons -->
<div class="spinning_icons">
<div class="social">
<a href="https://plus.google.com/100935445850301773475" rel="publisher" ><img src="../images/Google_Cracked-48x84.png" alt="bigInt Google Plus"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Bigint/574360432595073" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Facebook_Cracked-48x48.png" alt="Follow Us On Facebook"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/bigInt_biz" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Twitter_Cracked_48x48.png" alt="Follow Us On Twitter"></a>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/daniel-bye/51/b3b/ab2" target="_blank"><img src="../images/Linkedin_Cracked-48x48.png" alt=" photo Linkedin_Cracked.png"></a>
</div></div>


</br></br></br>


<!-- Top navigation bar-->
<div class="container">
       <div class="masthead">
         <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="Projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact_bigInt.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- End of top navigation bar-->

</header>





<!-- Asp.net body tag - no need to comment as in use -->
<div id="body">
   @RenderBody()
</div>

 @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

</body>

</html>

      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="../assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

---

Finally, here is demo.js with the function problem on line 29:

```
$(function(){

   // this is for the appbar-demo page
   if ($("#appbar-theme-select").length){
      $("#appbar-theme-select").change(function(){
         var ui = $(this).val();

         if (ui != '')
            $("footer.win-commandlayout")
               .removeClass("win-ui-light win-ui-dark")
               .addClass(ui);
      });
   }


   // style switcher 
   if ($("#win-theme-select").length){
      $("#win-theme-select").change(function(){
         var css = $(this).val();

         if (css != '')
            updateCSS(css);
      });
   }


   $("#settings").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#charms').charms('showSection', 'theme-charms-section'); // LINE 29
   });



   // listview demo
   $('#listview-grid-demo').on('click', '.mediumListIconTextItem', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   });


   //$('#home-carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});

});



//function to append a new theme stylesheet with the new style changes
function updateCSS(css){

   $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/css/' + css +'.css">');

   if($("link[href*=metro-ui-]").size() > 1){
      $("link[href*=metro-ui-]:first").remove();
   }

};



// NOTICE!! DO NOT USE ANY OF THIS JAVASCRIPT
// IT'S ALL JUST JUNK FOR OUR DOCS!
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

!function ($) {

   $(function(){

      var $window = $(window)

      // Disable certain links in docs
      $('section [href^=#]').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault()
      })

      // side bar
      $('.bs-docs-sidenav').affix({
         offset: {
            top: function () { return $window.width() <= 980 ? 290 : 210 }
            , bottom: 270
         }
      })

      // make code pretty
      window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()

      // add-ons
      $('.add-on :checkbox').on('click', function () {
         var $this = $(this)
            **, method = $this.attr('checked') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'
         $(this).parents('.add-on')[method]('active')
      })
      // add tipsies to grid for scaffolding
      if ($('#gridSystem').length) {
         $('#gridSystem').tooltip({
            selector: '.show-grid > div'
            , title: function () { return $(this).width() + 'px' }
         })
      }
      // tooltip demo
      $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
         selector: "a[rel=tooltip]"
      })
      $('.tooltip-test').tooltip()
      $('.popover-test').popover()
      // popover demo
      $("a[rel=popover]")
         .popover()
         .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
         })
      // button state demo
      $('#fat-btn')
         .click(function () {
            var btn = $(this)
            btn.button('loading')
            setTimeout(function () {
               btn.button('reset')
            }, 3000)
         })
      // carousel demo
      $('#myCarousel').carousel()
      // javascript build logic
      var inputsComponent = $("#components.download input")
         , inputsPlugin = $("#plugins.download input")
         , inputsVariables = $("#variables.download input")
      // toggle all plugin checkboxes
      $('#components.download .toggle-all').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         inputsComponent.attr('checked', !inputsComponent.is(':checked'))
      })
      $('#plugins.download .toggle-all').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         inputsPlugin.attr('checked', !inputsPlugin.is(':checked'))
      })
      $('#variables.download .toggle-all').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault()
         inputsVariables.val('')
      })
      // request built javascript
      $('.download-btn').on('click', function () {
         var css = $("#components.download input:checked")
               .map(function () { return this.value })
               .toArray()
            , js = $("#plugins.download input:checked")
               .map(function () { return this.value })
               .toArray()
            , vars = {}
            , img = ['glyphicons-halflings.png', 'glyphicons-halflings-white.png']
         $("#variables.download input")
            .each(function () {
               $(this).val() && (vars[ $(this).prev().text() ] = $(this).val())
            })
         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST'
            , url: /\?dev/.test(window.location) ? 'http://*l*o*c*a*l*h*o*s*t*:3000' : 'http://bootstrap.herokuapp.com'
            , dataType: 'jsonpi'
            , params: {
               js: js
               , css: css
               , vars: vars
               , img: img
            }
         })
      })
   })
   // Modified from the original jsonpi https://github.com/benvinegar/jquery-jsonpi
   $.ajaxTransport('jsonpi', function(opts, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
      var url = opts.url;
      return {
         send: function(_, completeCallback) {
            var name = 'jQuery_iframe_' + jQuery.now()
               , iframe, form
            iframe = $('<iframe>')
               .attr('name', name)
               .appendTo('head')
            form = $('<form>')
               .attr('method', opts.type) // GET or POST
               .attr('action', url)
               .attr('target', name)
            $.each(opts.params, function(k, v) {
               $('<input>')
                  .attr('type', 'hidden')
                  .attr('name', k)
                  .attr('value', typeof v == 'string' ? v : JSON.stringify(v))
                  .appendTo(form)
            })
            form.appendTo('body').submit()
         }
      }
   })
}(window.jQuery)**
```

---

I have had to strip quite a bit out of the pages to meet the allowed character limit in the code sections; everything should be there for the metroui background colour switch though.

Thanks everyone for looking/ helping.

Comment: it seems to me that you are including `jQuery` two times. Once at the end and once in the `head`

Comment: I might have missed something, but from what I can see you are adding a head section in your view which will be loaded in the middle of your body tag on your layout page, which could cause some unwanted behavior. If you want to add scripts to a certain page, in your cshtml page at the bottom you would do @section scripts {
...scripts...} you could also do the same thing for styles in your layout page you would put @RenderSection("styles", required: false) and a in a similar way to scripts you could add styles.

Comment: Tony, thanks SO much - it's working. Last night I used @section scripts but, I wasn't using *section scripts in the right place.  You made me look again. I dropped it to the bottom and although my like buttons stopped working there was no jquery error.  So, I moved the like scripts back and bingo everything works. How do I mark you as an answer please?  Thanks to everyone for your help it was really appreciated.

Comment: Tony, can you post the same post again but as an "answer" and not a co"comment" please?  Then, I can mark your post as an answer.  I have looked into how to mark your reply as the answer and how I can give you a vote and it seems this is the only option.  Thanks. Dan.

Comment: Check to see if razor is rendering your conditional comments.  <!--[if lt IE 7]>...<![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running the `cshtml` page from? What is the context?

`Charms()` seems like a metro function that isn't available from your current context. You probably have to explicitly add a reference to whatever library/script that holds that function/plugin.

Comment: Hey,thanks guys for the help. *Spokey I tried removing the other jquery ref yesterday (and again just now) but it makes no difference. *Tony the "header" section and not "head" was already in the asp.net starter project template in Webmatrix it is where they put their header so I used it - so it must be OK.  *agrothe I'm running the cshtml page from a default starter project in Webmatrix.  I am including pages with different themes in the same project.  This page works fine in html format in this same Razor cshtml project.  As soon as I put the working code into a cshtml page I get the error